# Riesz representation applied to $C_b(X)$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, dynamical-systems, ergodic-theory

Let $X$ be a locally compact complete separable metric space and $T:X \rightarrow X$ be continuous. Given $x \in X$, define $$\varphi_x(f) := \lim \frac{1}{n} \sum_{k = 0}^{n - 1} f(T^k(x))$$where $f \in C_b(X)$(only consider real codomains).

Assume that $\varphi_x(f)$ exists for every $f \in C_b(X)$. I have shown that $\varphi_x:C_b(X) \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is unital linear functional. I am confused about why we can use we can use Riesz Representation Theorem to assert that there exists a unique (Radon) probability measure $\mu$ such that $\varphi_x(f) = \int f d\mu$. Is this only for $C_c(X)$, does this work for $C_b(X)$? It wasn't that clear since in the notes that I am reading, he just stated that $\varphi_x(f) = \int f d\mu$. I understand how he is applying RRT.

Comment: Well, the measure $\mu$ lives on the Stone-Čech compactification $\beta X$ (since $C_b(X)$ is canonically isomorphic to $C(\beta X)$) so $\varphi_x(f)=\int_{\beta X}f\,\mathrm{d}\mu$.  You don't know if $\mu(\beta X-X)=0$ (indeed it probably doesn't -- let $X=\mathbb{N}$ and your $\varphi_x$ looks like a Banach limit for shift $T$).

Comment: ahh I see, I will just assume $X$ to be compact, and move on thanks.

Comment: @user10354138 It looks like existence of limit $\varphi_x(f)$ is strong restriction. Maybe $\{T^i(x)\}$ is relatively compact?